# Doing the opposite of CSS Sticky Footer

Tags: css, scroll, footer, absolute, sticky

I'm trying to do the reverse situation of StickyFooter: 
Footer should always be visible (it will overlap content), but should stick to the page content when the browser height exceeds the content (content will be a fixed height).

Basically, I want it to behave like position:fixed only when the browser height is smaller than content.

I have tried it through just CSS similarly to the way stickyfooter does (using max-height instead of min-height), but...

My problem: When the browser is smaller than the content, the footer sticks to the bottom initially, but then it doesn't keep sticking to bottom as you scroll. [As shown here](http://www.spatial-practice.com/reverse_stickyfooter.html)

I'm guessing there will be some javascript involved to keep it stuck to the bottom, but I haven't found a script that does this (and I don't know how to write one myself...)

Any help, suggestions, links would be very appreciated! Thanks.

```
HTML, BODY { height: 100%; 
   font-family: helvetica, arial; 
   font-size: 8pt;
   }
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
   position:relative;
   height:100%;
   max-height: 516px;
   }
#content {
   width:800px;
   height:400px;
   position: absolute;
   background: #999;
   border: 4px solid #000;
   }
#footer {
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 800px;
   background-color: yellow;
   border: 4px solid #f90;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

solved by applying

```
footer{
 position: sticky;
 bottom:0;
}
```

the Footer tag, that alone solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `margin-bottom: 100px` or more to the `body` class (which is the height of the footer) when the footer is positioned as fixed.